# PutCheckBoxes or Images into UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, universal, uniformgrid

I try to implement [Whac a mole game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole) in WPF.

Molehills are in *UniformGrid*. Depending on options molehills are checkboxes or images. And here comes the trouble.

I don't know how to implement *UniformGrid* to accept both *checkboxes* and *images*. 
Maybe you have better idea how I can solve it. Maybe *UniformGrid* for checkboxes and images isn't good idea.

I tried it this way:

```cs
<ItemsControl Name="GameBlocksItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=Moles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Conf.Cols}" 
                            Rows="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Conf.Rows}" 
                            Name="MolesGrid">
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Moles** is collection of **Object**s so that I can put there **Checkbox** or **BitmapImage**.

Unfortunately after adding to collection some **BitmapImage**s they aren't displayed correctly (instead of image there is written: *System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage*). If I add **CheckBox**es to collection they are displayed well.

I considered writing converter but such a converter would has to know if specified **Object** is **CheckBox** or **BitmapImage**. Even if it's possible to code, it's not very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would simply set the `ItemTemplate` based on the `SelectedViewOption`

For example, assuming `SelectedViewOption` is a string for simplicity:

```
<Style x:Key="MyItemsControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedViewOption}" Value="Image">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedViewOption}" Value="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This not only allows you to add other view options easily later on if you want to, but it also removes any view-specific code from your `DataContext`, such as `CheckBoxes` or `Images`. Typically you want your UI and Business Logic layers separate, and this allows you to do that.